# Error append line to excel file with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, append

I am getting error-messages, if i am running this code. I want to read users active directory data such as username, name, mail and append these informations to an xlsx file for license-tracking and ordering.

```
$user = Read-Host "Username"
$data = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties * | select SamAccountName,AdminDisplayName,EmailAddress
$user = $data.SamAccountName
$name = $data.AdminDisplayName
$mail = $data.EmailAddress
$clo = Read-Host "Alter Computername (Nur bei Übertrag)"
$cln = Read-Host "Neuer Computername"

if ($clo -ne '') {
    $out = "Übertrag: $($user), $($name), $($mail), Alter PC: $($clo), neuer PC: $($cln)"
}else {
    $kst = Read-Host "Kostenstelle"
    $out = "$($user), $($name), $($mail), PC: $($cln), KST: $kst"}




$excel_file_path = '"##PATHTOFILE#CENSORED#\test.xlsx"'

## Instantiate the COM object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excel_file_path)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("Tabelle1")
$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()

## Find the first row where the first 7 columns are empty
$row = ($ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows | ? { ($_.Value2 | ? {$_ -eq $null}).Count -eq 7 } | select -first 1).Row
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = 'COLUMN 1 Text'
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,2) = 'COLUMN 2 Text'
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,3) = 'COLUMN 3 Text'
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,4) = "$out"
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,5) = 'COLUMN 5 Text' 
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.Close()
$Excel.Quit(
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel))
Stop-Process -Name EXCEL -Force
```

Comment: Could you please post what errors you get?

Comment: Take a look at [ImportExcel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) - it'll save you a lot of work :)

Comment: Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In Zeile:28 Zeichen:1
+ $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = 'COLUMN 1 Text'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: We are not allowed to use external modules

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction does not return any value for $row for me:

```
$row = ($ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows | ? { ($_.Value2 | ? {$_ -eq $null}).Count -eq 7 } | select -first 1).Row
```

I tried to browse the worksheet until a row where the first 7 columns are empty is found, using a loop. It seems to be working.

```
$lastrow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

for ($row = 1; $row -le $lastrow; $row ++) {
    $test = $true
    foreach ($col in 1..7) {$test = $test -and ($ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,$col).Value2 -eq $null)}
    if ($test) {break}
    }
```